# PyTorch: how to let only chosen elements in a tensor be differentiable?

Tags: pytorch

Right now, I have a use case like following

`A` is a `torch.tensor` like following

```
A = 
[[1,x,y], 
 [1,2,3],
 [1,z,3]]
```

only elements `x, y, z` in `A` are differentiable, other elements are just constant.

For example, if the `cost = tr(A.A)`

`cost = 14 + 2 x + 2 y + 6 z`

When I do backtracking, I only want to differentiate and update with respect to `x, y, z`. Certainly this example is just a toy example, not the true complicated one.

How can I realize such use case?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to achieve it is to use a mask tensor to zero-out the gradients of the elements you don't want to modify, like this :

```
A = torch.tensor([[1.0, 100, 100], [1, 2, 3], [1, 100, 3]])
# I have initialized your x,y,z to 100, so the mask should only have these set to 1
mask = (A==100).to(dtype=torch.float32)
#optimizer to backpropagate
opt = torch.optim.SGD([A], lr=1e-2)
# optimization loop
for i in range(10):
    # backprop the loss gradient
    (A.matmul(A)).diag().pow(2).sum().backward()
    # mask the gradients
    with torch.no_grad():
        A.grad *= mask
    # optimization step
    opt.step()
    A.grad.zero_()
print(A)
```

Only the x,y,z coordinates should be modified then